# How to increase the EFI splash screen delay time on Virtualbox (5.1.18)?

Tags: virtualbox, uefi

On VirtualBox (At least as of 5.1.18), they show a brief splash screen when starting an EFI machine, but for a very short time. How can I increase this delay?

Using `--bioslogodisplaytime 3000` did not work.

Alternatively, is there a way to easily compile the EFI firmware for VirtualBox? I am familiar with stock OVMF but not with the Oracle-patched version.

Comment: You can use the '--bioslogodisplaytime' option

Comment: @Ramhound I will try this.

Comment: @Ramhound didn't work. I tried "--bioslogodisplaytime 3000" (hoping for 3 seconds). Please note this is a UEFI vm, not BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like EFI is still an experimental feature on VirtualBox 5.1.18. Its user manual goes as far as to say. :

> Note that the VirtualBox EFI support is experimental and will be enhanced as EFI matures and
>   becomes more widespread. While Mac OS X and Linux guests are known to work fine, Windows
>   guests are currently unable to boot with the VirtualBox EFI implementation.

source: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.18/UserManual.pdf (pg. 59 - "Section 3.13 Alternative Firmware (EFI)")

Also, in the same guide it covers all the flags/switches available for the `VBoxManage modifyvm` command. In that section it provides a way to increase display time for BIOS but it does not for EFI. Your desired functionality does not look to yet exist in VirtualBox.

I would recommend switching back to BIOS and using `--bioslogodisplaytime` to adjust the BIOS splash screen afterward:

`VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --firmware bios`

`VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --bioslogodisplaytime 3000`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this manual is outdated. I can successfully boot a Windows 8.1 VM using EFI. Do you know how to compile the EFI firmware for VirtualBox? I am familiar with stock OVMF but not with the Oracle-patched version.

Comment: @MarkYisri was the Windows VM guest you create with EFI on VirtualBox 5.1.18? Unfortunately, I don't know how to compile that. Best of luck on this!

Comment: Yes I created this on Virtualbox 5.1.18. 5.1 added support for this.

Comment: If no one else replies soon I will give you the bounty for your attempt.

Comment: @MarkYisri I certainly won't complain. :) Hopefully someone is able to find a super-awesome hidden flag you can use though. Out of curiosity have you tried seeing if something like `--efilogodisplaytime` works?

Comment: I looked, but that doesn't exist.

Comment: @MarkYisri I had the sudden realization that VirtualBox is open source. I downloaded the source code and scoured it for anything that might help but couldn't find anything. All references to a display timeout were BIOS specific, and the only option that even referenced EFI for modifyvm was the firmware type. In the code there was logic for a BIOS display timeout, but none for EFI. I think you're going to be out of luck on this one. :( I pulled from the latest source code just to be safe: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.22/VirtualBox-5.1.22.tar.bz2

Comment: I also downloaded the source code, and looked at it. My guess is that this setting is baked into the EFI firmware at build time (Virtualbox uses a modified version of Intel TianoCore/EDK2)

Comment: bounty is yours now

Comment: There is a `-delay` in the [VirtualBox EFI shell code](https://www.virtualbox.org/svn/vbox/trunk/src/VBox/Devices/EFI/Firmware/ShellPkg/Application/Shell/Shell.c) but I don't think this is exposed to the outside world. I tried `vboxmanage setextradata my_vm VBoxInternal2/EfiBootArgs "-delay 20"` with no effect, as expectedly these are booting args rather than shell args.